# BigInteger cannot represent infinity

Tags: c#, algorithm, biginteger

When i run this code  I get run-time exception

> OverflowException: BigInteger cannot represent infinity.

```
BigInteger sum=0;
for (double i=1 ; i<=1000 ;i++ )
    sum += (BigInteger) Math.Pow(i,i);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

From what I understand there should be no limit to `BigInteger` values. So why it throws `OverflowException`?

Comment: Most likely, you are exceeding the max value allowed by BigInteger, whatever that is.

Comment: @KevinH System.Numerics

Comment: I ran your code and it runs just fine im running under `.net framework 4.0`

Comment: @EZI  so Why it does not save the value of 1000^1000

Comment: @LCTS Predicticting that there are `10**80` hydrogen atoms in universe  `1000**1000` can be a big number :)) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_.E2.80.94_number_of_atoms

Comment: @ezi: for those working with big numbers, for whatever reason, especially those using arbitrary precision numbers, $10^3000$ isn't a big number, on the opposite, it is just 3000 digits long. What's the number of ways to permute all atoms in the universe ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happened because you exceeded the limit for `double`.

`Math.Pow` there is evaluated in `double`s, so a finite result can only be as big as about [1.7e308](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx), a number you exceed for `i = 144`. So it results in `double.PositiveInfinity`, which cannot be converted to `BigInteger`. `BigInteger` has no special representations for infinities the way `double` does, it can only store integers and infinity is not an integer - even if `BigInteger` had no limit, it would never reach infinity. There is actually also a limit to `BigInteger`, when the internal array it uses to store the number reaches its maximum size (you may run out of memory sooner).

In this case you can use `BigInteger.Pow` to avoid this, for example

```
BigInteger sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    sum += BigInteger.Pow(i, i);
```

The result is quite big, as expected.

Comment: @EZI how is that a reason for downvoting?

Comment: @Harold Do you expect more?

Comment: @EZI what are you even talking about?

Comment: @Harold even you use `BigInteger` you can not calculate `1000**1000`

Comment: @EZI http://ideone.com/oIJVPY  it is only a number of magnitude 1000**1000, that's only about 10k bits

Comment: @Harold, Now I do the embarrassing thing. retract my downvote (of course if you edit it). -- I did it.